# How to secure sip/voip server?

Tags: android, ios, voip, sip

For registration on voip server the standard port is 5060. For security reasons, iptables rules forbade requests for port 5060 from any addresses except one static (customer support).

Now the problem is that there are clients using dynamic ip-addresses (ios,android sip clients). By what principle would it be right to organize access to the server for such customers?

Comment: I don't think that the question can be answered in the current form. It looks like you want to restrict access to the port for specific clients but you give no details about the clients. Based on this no restrictions are possible. Apart from this, iptables can mostly restrict access only on IP+port, i.e. if you have any other criteria (which you don't say) you need to use application layer filtering.

Comment: Besides, SIP is typically UDP, which has far less guarantees than TCP about the origin IP address.